# Regular expression for set of strings

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to generate three regular expressions

1. First is strings containing 2G
2. Second is strings containing 3G
3. Third is strings containing 4G

The set of strings are:

```
- 4 GB+ 2 GB Night 3G/2G Data    #matches the exp generated by 1 and 2
- 500 MB 4G/3G data              #matches the exp generated by 3 and four 
- 3GB 2G/3G/4G data              #matches all the three
- 2GB 4G/3G/2G Data
```

The expression I made is capturing '2GB' '3GB' '4GB' too. I want to get rid of exp containing 'B'. I am new to regular expression.Please suggest a correct expression for above.

Comment: Perhaps including your regular expression would help?

Comment: negative lookahead/behind

Comment: Tip - Search for regex word boundary.

Comment: Which language/tool are you using? Word boundaries seem to work fine for all of your cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinguish `3GB` from `3G` you need to make certain the term ends after the `G`. This can be done using a *word boundary*. In regex it's done with the sequence `\b`.

So `\b[2-4]G\b` makes sure there isn't a letter, nor a digit, before the `2`, `3` or `4`, and the same after the `G`.

[Here's an illustration what it matches, and some that it doesn't, at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dNolyN/1).